# SQL select first letter of a word?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

In SQL how do you select just the first letter?

For example if i have a column called ColumnX and it has the value of "hippodarts" how do I select just the letter H?

Comment: Is the first letter always the first character, or could it be preceeded by spaces or numbers?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To get the first letter of a **STRING** you can use left:

`SELECT LEFT(ColumnX, 1)`

To do it for a **word** within a string is more complicated.

Answer (score 7):

```
Select LEFT(COLUMNX, 1) From Table
```

Answer (score 6):

By using [SUBSTRING()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx)

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(columnname, 1, 1) AS firstletter FROM tablename
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Description

You can use the T-SQL function `substring` or `left`

#### Sample

**Substring**

```
SELECT substring(ColumnX,1,1) FROM YOURTABLENAME
```

**left**

```
SELECT LEFT(ColumnX, 1) FROM YOURTABLENAME
```

#### More Information

- [MSDN - SUBSTRING (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx)
- [MSDN - LEFT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

SELECT LEFT(ColumnX,1) FROM Table

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Another option!

```
SELECT CAST(your_col AS CHAR(1))
FROM your_table
```